# Ordering of Spring `@Configuration` classes

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

Is it possible to enforce ordering of two `@Configuration` classes?

Case I have is that in one of the configuration classes (`ConsumerConfiguration`) I declare `@Bean` of `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
            new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("queue");
    return container;
}
```

which is supposed to listen to a `queue`. (It's a part of Spring Integration + AMQP project)

My assumption is that all Rabbit components would be created beforehand and I normally don't want to declare them in Java. However, for `dev` profile I would like the application to create them for me, hence another `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Profile("dev")
public class ConsumerBindingConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public Exchange exchange() {
        return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange("exchange")
                .durable()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("queue")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue())
                .to(exchange())
                .with("key")
                .noargs();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the application, the `ConsumerConfiguration` class is being run first. Seems that `@Order` annotation is not working for `@Configuration` classes. I saw `@DependsOn` annotation, but I can't use it in my case (for any profile different than `dev` I don't want to declare the queue).

Comment: What do you mean by "run first"? Why is it an issue? Spring first creates all bean definitions from all classes before it starts instantiating the beans.

Comment: I don't see `AmqpAdmin` in your code: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, your comment got me thinking... I started even creating a sample project reflecting the issue, when it struck me. I had another `BindingConfiguration` with beans of the same name (another `exchange()`, `queue()` and `binding()`). When I resolved duplicated names everything works...
Fun fact: depending on configuration class name Spring loaded `queue()` bean from first configuration or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ConsumerBindingConfiguration.class})
public class ConsumerConfiguration
```

Comment: It did not help.